# Why am I randomly getting a 401 sometimes and not others using two different authentication policies?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, aws-lambda, jwt, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm attempting to set up two different authorization policies called 'portal' and 'api' on our .NET Core 2.1 project hosted on a AWS Lambda environment. The first is the default policy that is used by the front-end site, and the latter is used by developers seeking to use our external API. I want each one to be signed with a different IssuerSigningKey so that users cannot use the bearer token they receive interchangeably with the two different services.

The problem I'm having is that the bearer token generated to access the 'api' policy works sometimes, but not others. I will get five 401s in a row, then followed by several 200s, then back to 401s. Seems very random. The errors I'm getting when the 401s show up are

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler: Failed to validate the token.
```

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler: portal was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey , KeyId: 
'.
Exceptions caught:
 ''.
token: '
{
    "alg": "HS512",
    "typ": "JWT"
}
.
{
    "nameid": "88",
    "unique_name": "my@email.com",
    "role": "apiAccess",
    "nbf": 1596835699,
    "exp": 1596839299,
    "iat": 1596835699
}
'.
```

Which implies to me that sometimes it's not attempting to use the 'api' policy to validate the bearer token, but instead it's defaulting to 'portal'.

Here is a sample in Startup.cs where I set this all up.

```
...

                serviceDependencies
                .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer("portal", options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(portalAccessKey),
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        ValidateLifetime = true
                    };
                })
                .AddJwtBearer("api", options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(apiAccessKey),
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        ValidateLifetime = false
                    };
                });

            serviceDependencies.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes("portal")
                    .Build();

                options.AddPolicy("MeteredAccess", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes("api")
                    .RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "apiAccess")
                    .Build());
            });
...
```

And the MVC endpoint I am applying the policy to is

```
[Authorize(Policy = "MeteredAccess")]
[HttpPost("api/objects/save")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ApiCreateObject([FromBody] CoreEngineObjectFormData data)
{
    if(!(await _authService.UpdateUserApiAuthentications(UserId))) 
        return StatusCode(429);

    var result = await _coreEngineService.CreateCoreEngineObject(data);

    return Ok(result);
}
```

I never have this problem with the default policy, requests made from the front-end work every time.

Also, a big thing to mention is that I don't have this problem at all when I run the project locally under IIS Express, it's only after I deploy the project AWS Lambda that this starts to happen. I suspect that something about the lambda's lifetime may have something to do with this.